# R data.table: efficiently access and update a variable column name in j expression with grouping

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I want to apply a transformation (whose type, loosely speaking, is "vector" -> "vector") to a list of columns in a data table, and this transformation will involve a grouping operation.

Here is the setup and what I would like to achieve:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
DT <- data.table(
        date = seq.Date(as.Date('2000/1/1'), by='day', length.out = n),
        A = runif(n),
        B = rnorm(n),
        C = rexp(n))

DT[, A.prime := (A - mean(A))/sd(A), by=year(date)]
DT[, B.prime := (B - mean(B))/sd(B), by=year(date)]
DT[, C.prime := (C - mean(C))/sd(C), by=year(date)]
```

The goal is to avoid typing out the column names. In my actual application, I have a list of columns I would like to apply this transformation to.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
DT <- data.table(
        date = seq.Date(as.Date('2000/1/1'), by='day', length.out = n),
        A = runif(n),
        B = rnorm(n),
        C = rexp(n))

columns <- c("A", "B", "C")

for (x in columns) {
    # This doesn't work.
    # target <- DT[, (x - mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), by=year(date)]

    # This doesn't work.
    #target <- DT[, (..x - mean(..x, na.rm=TRUE))/sd(..x, na.rm = TRUE), by=year(date)]

    # THIS WORKS! But it is tedious writing "get(x)" every time. 
    target <- DT[, (get(x) - mean(get(x), na.rm=TRUE))/sd(get(x), na.rm = TRUE), by=year(date)][, V1]

    set(DT, j = paste0(x, ".prime"), value = target)
}
```

**Question:** What is the idiomatic way to achieve the above result? There are two things which may be possibly be improved:

1. How to avoid typing out `get(x)` every time I use `x` to access a column?
2. Is accessing `[, V1]` the most efficient way of doing this? Is it possible to update `DT` directly by reference, without creating an intermediate data.table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.SDcols` to specify the columns that you want to operate on :

```
library(data.table)

columns <- c("A", "B", "C")
newcolumns <- paste0(columns, ".prime")

DT[, (newcolumns) := lapply(.SD, function(x) (x- mean(x))/sd(x)),
                      year(date), .SDcols = columns]
```

This avoids using `get(x)` everytime and updates `data.table` by reference.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think Ronak's answer is superior & preferable, just writing this to demonstrate a common syntax for more complicated `j` queries is to use a full `{}` expression:

```
target <- DT[ , by = year(date), {
  xval = eval(as.name(x))
  (xval - mean(xval, na.rm=TRUE))/sd(xval, na.rm = TRUE)
}]$V1
```

Two other small differences:

- I used `eval(as.name(.))` instead of `get`; the former is more trustworthy & IME faster
- I replaced `[ , V1]` with `$V1` -- the former requires the overhead of `[.data.table`.

You might also like to know that the `base` function `scale` will do the center & normalize steps more concisely (if slightly inefficient for being a bit to general).

Comment: Thanks for this answer Michael, learned a lot!